# mysql union different databases but the same schema

Tags: mysql, union

as picture(phpmyadmin),I have tables in the database **week1** the tables are now empty.

I have another databases with exactly the same sql schema **w1moninside** and **w1monoutside**
but they have values.

I want to **union** these two and insert them in week1 
what should I do?
I inserted the picture just for clearance.unoin for one of the tables for example the first one, **data** 
is enough for me

Thanks.

[image]

```
mysql> describe w1moninside.data;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| data_payload | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into week1.TableName (column list)
select column list from w1moninside.TableName where...
union
select column list from w1monoutside.TableName where
```

Comment: I tried this one insert into week1.data select * from w1moninside.data union select * from w1monoutside.data ; but I have this Error 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Do you have some identical values in your w1moninside.TableName and w1monoutside.TableName???

Comment: No,you can but problem is that both of them have same key values.Now you can do one thing just remove week1.TableName from this.

Comment: I updated the question with the structure I should remove primary key? ok let me try

Comment: sorry I shouldn't do it I should use the sql schema like before

Comment: for inserting purpose do that and after insertion alter table and you can make primary key again.

Comment: I can insert another key auto increment ID so that each one would be different hah?humm

Comment: you can also do this depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into week1 (column list)
select column list from dbname.w1moninside where...
union
select column list from dbname.w1monoutside where..
```

Comment: week1 is a database I don't get your query would you please tell me?